# in R shiny, how to make selectInput as title of div (h1 tag)

Tags: html, r, shiny

I have a `selectInput` in my shiny app, and I want every input to this `selectInput` to change the h1 title of my `fluidRow` div. I am trying to use glue package but it’s not working.

This is my app:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  fluidRow(
    column(6,
           selectInput('names',
                       label = "Selection",
                       choices= names(mtcars))),
    column(6,
           tags$html(h1(glue::glue("title {input$names}"))))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

What is the best practice to change html elements when shiny inputs are changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change to `htmlOutput` in the UI, and then on the server side use renderUI.

UI:

```
htmlOutput("title")
```

Server:

```
output$title <- renderUI({
  HTML(<h1>paste0("title: ", input$names))
})
```